# An inequality related to the L series of Ramanujan tau function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Let $j, k, n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\tau(k)$ be the Ramanujan tau function and let
$$S(n,j)=\frac{1}{\tau(n) n^j}\sum_{k=1}^n \tau(k) k^j. \tag{1}$$
Numerical results for several values of $j, n$ showed that $S(n,j)>0$.  Thus we are led to believe that 
$$S(n,j)>0 \tag{2}$$
To remove the potential rare possibility of $\tau(n)=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we would like to replace $n$ with $7^n$ and try to prove
$$S(7^n,j)>0 \tag{3}.$$

Does there exist a counter example or a proof?

This problem showed up when we study the zeros of the L function associated with the Ramanujan tau-function:
$$L_{\tau}(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\tau(k)}{ k^s}\quad Re(s)>\frac{13}{2}\tag{4}$$

Thanks

-mike

Comment: By dividing $\tau(n)$, the function $S(n,j)$, for fix $n$, seemed to go to 1 as $j$ increases.  This is just for convenience.  Anyway, I am looking for a proof for $sign(\tau(n))\sum_{k=1}^n \tau(k) k^j>0$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the comment!  But I do not quite understand your question.  The integer $j$ does not take the value of 0; it starts from 1,2,3...

Comment: @reuns. I did what you suggested and observed what you mentioned.  But I do not see the link between what you said and what I try to prove that $S(7^n,j)>0$.  Are you saying that this is not true and you tried to show me a counter example?

Comment: For $j=0$ you are asking if the signs of the coefficients of $(1-q)^{23}\prod_{m \ge 2}(1-q^m)^{24}$ and $(1-q)^{23}\prod_{m \ge 2}(1-q^m)^{24}$ are the same. For $j= 1$ it is quite messier, $\Delta' - 12 E_2 \Delta$ is a modular form thus a polynomial in $E_4,E_6$. 
What does it **change** if the signs agree or not ? Try in pari/gp `N = 20; Delta=q*prod(n=1,N,(1-q^n)^24+O(q^N)); 
dDelta = deriv(Delta,q); print( dDelta,"\n", dDelta/(1-q));`the signs disagree at $q^{17}$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\tau(k)}{ k^s}$ converges (at least) for $\Re(s) > 13/2$ you are confusing with the normalized L-function $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\tau(k)k^{-11/2}}{ k^s}$ whose coefficients [are $O(k^\epsilon)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Petersson_conjecture)

Comment: @reuns. I corrected my mistake so that $Re(s)>13/2$. Thanks!